# Pandas to_sql with sqlAlchemy duplicate entries error in mysqldb

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using PANDAS with a SQLAlchemy to write to MYSQL DB using `DataFrame.to_sql`.  I like to turn on the flag for `'append' --> df.to_sql(con=con, name='tablename', if_exists='append')` Since the program does several small writes to the tables during the day, I don't want the entire table overwritten with replace.  Periodically, I get the duplicate entry error:

```
sqla: valuesToCalc has error:  (IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 
 '0-0000-00-00-00:00:00' for key 'PRIMARY'") 'INSERT INTO valuesToCalc () VALUES ()' ()
```

Any way to add the syntax `"on duplicate key update"` to a pd.to_sql ?  Do I have to stop using `to_sql` and go directly with sqlAlchemy? I was hoping not to.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if you found an answer but here's a workaround that worked for me:

call the `.to_sql()` on a temporary table then use a query to update the main table with the temp table. Then you can drop the temp table. So for example:

```
df.to_sql(con=con, name='tablename_temp', if_exists='replace')
connection = con.connect()
connection.execute(text("INSERT INTO tablename SELECT * FROM tablename_temp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tablename.field_to_update=tablename_temp.field_to_update"))
connection.execute(text('DROP TABLE tablename_temp '))
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    #df is a dataframe
    num_rows = len(df)
    #Iterate one row at a time
    for i in range(num_rows):
        try:
            #Try inserting the row
            df.iloc[i:i+1].to_sql(name="Table_Name",con = Engine_Name,if_exists = 'append',index=False)
        except IntegrityError:
            #Ignore duplicates
            pass
```

Comment: This is quite inefficient btw, would not recommend.